# Include .shtml file in a .php page?

Tags: php, html, shtml

I'd like to include a .shtml file in a .php page. I know it is possible, as i have done it before (though i've forgotten the code). Please can someone help?

Comment: Why not just use a php include or file_get_contents? shtml isn't used much these days.

Comment: my site is written entirely in shtml. i am writing a php application and must be able to include a shtml file

Comment: What do you want to archive exactly?

Comment: basically i have header.shtml file which i need to include in home.php

Comment: You might be looking for [`virtual`](http://php.net/virtual).

Comment: how would i go about doing it? i am using this code <?php include ("/includes/header.shtml');> it doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using:

```
include_once('/includes/header.shtml');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
 echo file_get_contents('/includes/header.shtml');
 // or
 echo file_get_contents('includes/header.shtml');
```

It might work.

But I would just start converting all the templates to any of available php templating engines.

Comment: What is your folder structure.

Comment: Can us tell what is your folder layout. As `'/include/header.shtml'` does not seam right

Comment: /includes/header.shtml is correct since the folder "includes" is in the top-level of the domain and the shtml file is within it. the test.php file is in a folder also in the top-level of the domain.

Comment: Based on your last comment I was right. You need `echo file_get_contents('includes/header.shtml');` or even just `require 'includes/header.shtml';` would work. Just try it.

Comment: i have used: <?php require 'includes/header.shtml'; ?> and know test.php is displaying a blank page.

Comment: I've found out it only works when specifying an absolute url, e.g. `echo file_get_contents('http://sitename.com/file.shtml');`. Otherwise, the SSI will not parse and remain HTML comments.